# Use null check or prefer empty method?

Tags: java, performance, coding-style

### Scenario

I want to provide a possibility to *optionally* add callbacks in my working classes. An interface of such a callback may look something like that:

```
public interface Callback<T> {

    void callback(final T data);

}
```

Because the callbacks are optional, I'd need to check if one is set inside a working class every time before calling it:

```
public void doWork(final T data) {
    if (callback != null) {
        callback.callback(data);
    }

    // do the actual work
}
```

### Idea

So I wonder if it is a good idea to have a no-operation callback instead which looks something like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class NopCallback implements Callback {

    public static final NopCallback CALLBACK = new NopCallback();

    @Override
    public void callback(final Object data) {
        // do nothing
    }

}
```

The worker would have its callback set to this NopCallback by default:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Worker() {
    callback = NopCallback.CALLBACK;
}
```

### Actual question

I've already found out that the Nop variant seems to perform better (by calling `doWork(...)` a few 1000 times and measure the duration with each variant). The thing I'm not totally happy with is the need of the `@SuppressWarnings`. I know I could get rid of them but then I'd need an own instance of NopCallback in each of my working classes.

Long story short, is the use of such a no operation callback a good idea in sense of *clean code*, *readability*, *performance* etc. or are there any other (elegant) alternatives?

Comment: What you are describing is `smart proxy delegation`, there is quite a lot of examples out there already to do exactly this.

Comment: In the big picture, will you care? If you only call this thing 10^6 times per second, it will make too little difference to matter.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Of course it won't matter after all because the actual callback implementations and the worker itself will need much much much more time. It's more ruminating about what's the best possible solution.

Comment: I understand that. These are the things people focus on, when *real* speedups are hiding just out of sight. Sorry to harp on the point, but it's almost universal that I see people splitting hairs when their software can easily have room for *gigantic* speedups, once they get a sense of perspective. [*I made a (very amateur) video about this.*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPg3sRpdW1U) It's like the old joke about the drunk looking under the street light for his keys, because that's where the light is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks quite elegant to me. It's basically the same idiom as `Collections.emptyList()`, which returns always the same, empty, immutable list. I wouldn't make it a public class though, but would use a factory method to get it, to make sure the warning is only at a single place, and the rest of the code is type-safe:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static final Callback NOP = new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void callback(final Object data) {
        // do nothing
    }
};

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static final <T> Callback<T> nop() {
    return (Callback<T>) NOP;
}
```

This is how `Collections.emptyList()` is implemented.

Comment: That's what I was going to say, but you beat me to it. +1

Comment: I wonder why I didn't think of this myself. :) Thank you, I really like this one.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, I've found another solution for my very special use case. Because all working classes have the same parent class anyway (e.g. `Worker`), I can have this `Worker` implement the `Callback` interface itself:

```
public abstract class Worker<T> implements Callback<T> {

    private Callback<T> callback;

    public Worker() {
        setCallback(this);
    }

    public void doWork(final T data) {
        callback.callback(data);

        doRealWork(data);
    }

    protected abstract void doRealWork(final T data);

    @Override
    public void callback(final T data) {
        // do nothing
    }

    public void setCallback(final Callback<T> callback) {
        if (callback == null) {
            this.callback = this;
            // Or throw some exception (depending on your situation)
        } else {
            this.callback = callback;
        }
    }

}
```

In my special use case it is also no problem that the callback method exists and is accessible in the workers themselfes.

Comment: In addition to having the class initialize the callback, I might be inclined to have the `setCallBack` method replace a passed-in `null` with `this`, so that code which wants to disable the callback will have a consistent pattern for doing so.  Assuming the callback will be invoked more often than it will be set, putting the null-check there would be more efficient than having it within `doWork`.